# android device dimensions in inches and density independent pixel (dp) counts

Tags: android

is there any resources, such as tables or calculators, related to android devices, available on the mapping between physical screen dimensions (in inches) and their typical density independent pixel (dp) count? for example, what is the typical dp count on screens of sizes for 3.5 / 4 / 7 / 10.1 inches? this is handy as, in terms of size variations, most devices falls on one of the aforementioned dimensions (like 4 inches for phones and 7 inches for tablets) and it may probably help others too if such mapping exists. thanks in advance!

Comment: go through the android UI guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a website which collects information about viewport sizes (i. e. sizes in dp) of different devices:

http://viewportsizes.com/

Most phones have 320 and 360 dp width in portrait orientation, most `7"` tablets have shortest  `width 600 dp` in portrait orientation, most `10"` tablets have shortest `width 720 dp`.

Comment: i have a little question - are the values mentioned in the web site measured in dp (device independent pixels), not px (pixels)?

Comment: they are given in dp there. By the way, sizes of most devices in dp are quite typical.

Comment: community did corrections in my answer, but I still think that 720 width for 10-inch tablets is incorrect. The most popular models such as Nexus 10, all Samsung 10-inch Galaxy Tabs and Sony Tablet S have screen dimensions 1280*800 dp.

Answer (score 0):

you can differentiate between device via device's status bar height,
`int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen",
                "android");
        if (resId > 0) {
        }

```
    switch (getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId)) {

    case 25: // small screen


        break;
    case 50:// for galaxy s3's status bar height

        break;
    case 75:

        break;
    case 38:


        break;

    default:
```

`

and here is the link  , its gives you all information about display of all type of devices.

http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php

hope your problem got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your Total Screen DP is Device Width * (dpi).

DPI varies based on Device Density. its `1` pixels for `MDPI` devices and so on. You can calculate the same for height as well for all devices. U can find online sites to do this calculation

The one I use is :

[Angry Tools](http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find what you need and more in [Material Design](https://material.io/tools/devices/).